# get data after a dispatch from store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to get my store data after an async dispatch in a components mount any idea how can I have the data I want?

my code

```
import React from "react";
import Page from "./Page";
import CheckDetail from "./CheckDetail";
import Header from "./Header";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { startSetSymlinkCheck } from "../actions/checks";

class Symlink extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.match.params.token);
            this.props.startSetSymlinkCheck(this.props.match.params.token).then(res => {
              console.log(this.props.getCheckId);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="route-container">
                <Header />
                <div className="page">
                    {/* <CheckDetail id={this.props.match.params.id} /> */}
                </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
      startSetSymlinkCheck: token => dispatch(startSetSymlinkCheck(token))
});

export default connect(
    undefined,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Symlink);
```

i want to get data after this.props.startSetSymlinkCheck finished and pass it to checkDetail

Comment: You need to dispatch success or failure handlers in your this.props.startSetSymlinkCheck and save the data in your store. Then you can access the data by return data from mapStateToProps. This is just high level view. Please see react redux integration section in redux blogs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add mapStateToProps function

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  console.log(state) //you should have some data here if redux is setup correctly
}
```

and connect your component to it

```
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Symlink);
```